# Hover effect on hyperlink not working properly after switching table into mobile view

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, mousehover

I have a table with several columns that can be switched into mobile view by clicking a button. Some fields contain hyperlinks.

```
       <style>

           .show-thin {
            width: 930px;      /* complete width of alternative table view */
           }

            /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
           .show-thin table, .show-thin thead, .show-thin tbody, .show-thin th, .show-thin td, .show-thin tr {
                    display: block;
            }

            /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
           .show-thin thead tr {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: -9999px;
                    left: -9999px;
            }

           .show-thin tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

           .show-thin td {
                    /* Behave  like a "row" */
                    border: none;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #eef;
                    position: relative;
                    padding-left: 30%;      /* distance of table-values from left margin 30px */
            }

           .show-thin td:before {
                    /* Now like a table header */
                    position: absolute;              /* puts field-names at left margin */
                    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
                    top: 6px;
                    left: 6px;
                    width: 45%;
                    padding-right: 10px;
                    white-space: nowrap;
            }

            /*
            Label the data
            */
           .show-thin td:before { content: attr(data-label); }

        </style>

        <script>

        function toggle() {
          var table = document.querySelector('.myTable');
          table.classList.toggle('show-thin');
        }

        </script>


        <button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
        <hr/>
        <table class="myTable">
        <thead>
          <tr class="tr thin-hide">
            <th data-label='Nr'>Nr</th>
            <th>Estimated arrival date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Period</th>
            <th>Period2</th>
            <th>Period3</th>
            <th>Period4</th>
            <th>Period5</th>
            <th>Period6</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td data-label="Nr">1234</td>
            <td data-label="Estimated Arrival Date">03/15/2001</td>
            <td data-label="Amount">$1.00</td>
            <td data-label="Period"><a href='https://www.startpage.com' target='_blank'>Startpage</a></td>
            <td data-label="Period2"><a href='https://www.wikipedia.com' target='_blank'>Wikipedia</a></td>
            <td data-label="Period3"><a href='https://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Google</a></td>
            <td data-label="Period4">3rd</td>
            <td data-label="Period5">3rd</td>
            <td data-label="Period6">3rd</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tr">
            <td data-label="Account">1235</td>
            <td data-label="Estimated Arrival Date">04/21/2002</td>
            <td data-label="Amount">$12.00</td>
            <td data-label="Period">4th</td>
            <td data-label="Period2">4th</td>
            <td data-label="Period3">4th</td>
            <td data-label="Period4">4th</td>
            <td data-label="Period5">4th</td>
            <td data-label="Period6">4th</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-label="Account">4594</td>
            <td data-label="Estimated Arrival Date">11/11/2011</td>
            <td data-label="Amount">$45.50</td>
            <td data-label="Period">2nd</td>
            <td data-label="Period2">2nd</td>
            <td data-label="Period3">2nd</td>
            <td data-label="Period4">2nd</td>
            <td data-label="Period5">2nd</td>
            <td data-label="Period6">2nd</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-label="Account">4594</td>
            <td data-label="Estimated Arrival Date">11/11/2011</td>
            <td data-label="Amount">$45.50</td>
            <td data-label="Period">2nd</td>
            <td data-label="Period2">2nd</td>
            <td data-label="Period3">2nd</td>
            <td data-label="Period4">2nd</td>
            <td data-label="Period5">2nd</td>
            <td data-label="Period6">2nd</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

In desktop mode the hover effect of the hyperlinks works as it should.
After switching into mobile view the hover effect of the hyperlinks works only in the very upper margin of the respective words.

I think the problem is in the CSS, however, I didn´t get it to work properly.

Comment: _“the hover effect of the hyperlinks works only in the very upper margin of the respective words”_ - then the rest of them is probably overlapped by some other element. Use your browser dev tools, right click on a link in an area where it is not working, and inspect to see what element is actually there.

Comment: Put this `[outlines="1"] :hover { outline: 2px dashed Crimson; background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.2) }` as last line in your CSS and modify `<body>` to `<body outlines="1">`. It is a nice little debug helper and will show all the element outlines on hover. At least now you can see what's going on. Anything other than '1' will switch it off....

Comment: I see at least 3 errors with the code you gave: 2 missing `<a>` (or 2 `</a>` too many) and a missing `</a>`. Correct those first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mobile mode the the first column overlaps the second column. Add `background-color: green` to `.show-thin td:before {...}` and you will see it happen. Ergo, the first column is too wide.

Change `width` in `.show-thin td:before {...}` to `28%` or less and your problem is solved....